# Requests.post returns top 50 records only even after setting offset and limit

Tags: python-3.x, restful-url, business-objects

I am running query in CI_INFOOBJECTS to fetch all the webi documents present in root folder and subfolders.
This query returns 70 records in Query Builder but when i am running it using requests.post, it gives me top 50 records only. I tried changing offset and limit but still returning same 50 records.
Can anyone help me resolve this as this is the best solution that i found till now to get all the reports from folders and sub folders to update the source universe.

```
folder_get = requests.get(bip_url + '/v1/cmsquery', headers=headers)
folder_root = etree.fromstring(folder_get.text)

Query_var = 'SELECT SI_ID,SI_NAME FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE SI_KIND = \'WEBI\' AND SI_ANCESTOR = 6526 ORDER BY SI_ID'

folder_root[0].text = Query_var

data1 = etree.tostring(folder_root)

folder_post = requests.post(bip_url + '/v1/cmsquery?offset=51&limit=100', headers = headers, data = data1)
folder_post.content
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `page` and `pagesize` instead of `offset` and `limit`.

```
folder_post = requests.post(bip_url + '/v1/cmsquery?page=1&pagesize=100', headers = headers, data = data1)
```

This should give you the 70 records that you expect.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot. Does pagesize=100 means 100 records ?

Comment: I may need more then 100 may be 4000 or 5000, Do i have to loop through it or just setting the pagesize is fine. I mean is there any limit ?

Comment: Yes. It's the number of records per page. It defaults to 50 which is why you were only getting the first 50.

Comment: re max pagsize I don't know. I just looked those parameters up in the documentation. But. if you look at the response you will see a number of URLs for first page, next page, and last page, so you can use that to iterate over the available results. Here is the reference: https://help.sap.com/viewer/db6a17c0d1214fd6971de66ea0122378/LATEST/en-US/ca2bd2aedebe4972ad9d26f0e80eb784.html

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it was very useful , i was able to fetch all my reports (Approx 2000) with this.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers again :)